# The API gives me identical resource-id for two different channels

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar API and push notifications to add channels and watch those channels for new events that come in. However while tracking weird behavior with mixing calendar accounts and events I found out that the resource ID that the calendar API responded with is the same across two accounts.

I am not sure if this is the culprit yet but this is the definition of resource-ID from docs

> X-Goog-Resource-ID - An opaque value that identifies the watched
>   resource. This ID is stable across API versions.

In my mind this means it should be unique. Resource-ID and channel-ID are a requirement for stopping channels after all.

Examples of identical resource-ID from google for two different accounts

Account 1

```
X-Goog-Resource-State: exists
X-Goog-Channel-Token: 56cab177e67348d9a17c7502a4bad513
X-Goog-Resource-ID: 8KXz6YKChAJDYMTUo0SoKqV8_7E
X-Goog-Channel-ID: ++7mlvx6pEIsTNeMpMwNLw==
```

Account 2

```
X-Goog-Resource-State: exists
X-Goog-Channel-Token: 4535832bc5cf47f7ae3403c404023bfd
X-Goog-Resource-ID: 8KXz6YKChAJDYMTUo0SoKqV8_7E
X-Goog-Channel-ID: mL+HzrG8/EYc7zRZdQ+6yw==
```

My question is, is this normal behaviour?

Comment: I don't think this is the normal behavior. As mentioned in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push), the `resourceId` is the ID of the watched resource. However, I've seen in this [article](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars#resource-representations) that the `resourceId` is the unique ID for the calendar resource. This resource ID is used in every API request. If the resource is created within the control panel, this ID is a series of random numbers.

Comment: @abielita hey thank you for the comment. My thoughts as well, is it possible its a bug from google calendar?

Comment: You can file a bug in this link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=824103

Answer (score 3):

The push notifications channel does not provide updates on individual events. It only tells you when the calendar (collection of events) changed.

To find changes to events, you want to look up [syncing](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/sync).
With syncing, you send in a token you got from the last time you synced to the List API endpoint. Instead of listing all events, it will list only the ones that changed since your last since request, represented by the sync token.

You can POST to the List API any time you want to get changes to events, but the push notifications you described help tell you when there would be a meaningful change to call the sync.